# Android app's communication with server (php + postgree)

Tags: php, android, database, communication

I need to develop simple app for android which does some communication with server. Purpose:
1) it needs put data into db through php 
2) needs to receive commands and data from server

Server side is php + postgree db.
I'd like to ask what is the most simple and efficient way to implement communication.

Regarding to 1) point i thing that I can just use http (put data in http's parameters) and php will parse it and put to db. Do you know any http libraries for android ?

About 2) point, php need to send data to android client. I am not sure how to implement server-> client way. Maybe by sockets, but not sure yet. Could you give me Your opinion about it ?

Comment: about 1) http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html about 2) if you keep opened connection between android device and server you ll drain battery quickly, frequent polling will do the same ... use C2DM to inform device about changes on server and let device connect to server to get em

Answer (score 0):

1) you can use Apache HttpComponents (https://hc.apache.org/)

2) the simplest way to do that is the polling: your Android client have to send a request ("do you have something for me?"), every x seconds, to the server that respond ("yes"/"no"). Other techniques (websocket, http streaming, ecc.) are more complex to implement

Comment: Ok, thanks for help. I would use first option, just asking db in time interval.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a SOA (Service Oriented Architecture). You will have and Android application that communicates with a PHP web service which in turn queries the Postgree database. The service will be used for all your `SELECT` queries as well as other CRUD operations.